# Add class on click without v-for or without duplicating click events

Tags: jquery, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

Coming from a jquery background where you can just go:

```
$(".faq-option").on("click",function(){
    $(".faq-selected").removeClass("faq-selected");
    $(this).addClass("faq-selected");
})
```

and it works on any of the `.faq-option` elements in the DOM. Is there any comparable way to do this **without** either adding a `@click` event to all the options or **without** using a `v-for` and looping over an array of elements and constructing the elements this way?

```
<div class="faq-contents">
    <div class="faq-option faq-selected">
        <div class="faq-title">Question 1</div>
        <div class="faq-answer">Answer 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="faq-option faq-selected">
        <div class="faq-title">Question 2</div>
        <div class="faq-answer">Answer 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="faq-option faq-selected">
        <div class="faq-title">Question 3</div>
        <div class="faq-answer">Answer 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v-for` and `@click` are basics of `Vue` and should be used for simple tasks in most cases.

If you don't want to use Vue the way it is intended to use, and want to programm Vue like jQuery, then *you don't need Vue.js*.

Simply use jQuery further.

Here is the typical Vue (v3) Version

```js
const { createApp } = Vue

const App = {
  data() {
    return { 
      selected: 1, 
      options: [
        { id: 1, title: 'Question 1', answer: 'Answer 1'},
        { id: 2, title: 'Question 2', answer: 'Answer 2' },
        { id: 3, title: 'Question 3', answer: 'Answer 3' },
      ]
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
.faq-option { margin: 4px; padding: 4px; }
.faq-selected { background-color: lightgrey; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <b>Selected</b>: Question {{selected}}<br/>
  <div class="faq-contents">    
      <div v-for="option in options" 
            :class="['faq-option', selected == option.id ? 'faq-selected': '']"
            @click="selected = option.id">                  
         <div class="faq-title">{{option.title}}</div>
         <div class="faq-answer">{{option.answer}}</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

jQuery Version

```js
$(".faq-option").on("click",function(){
    $(".faq-selected").removeClass("faq-selected");
    $(this).addClass("faq-selected");
})
```

```css
.faq-option { margin: 4px; padding: 4px; }
.faq-selected { background-color: lightgrey; }
```

```html
<div class="faq-contents">
    <div class="faq-option faq-selected">
        <div class="faq-title">Question 1</div>
        <div class="faq-answer">Answer 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="faq-option">
        <div class="faq-title">Question 2</div>
        <div class="faq-answer">Answer 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="faq-option">
        <div class="faq-title">Question 3</div>
        <div class="faq-answer">Answer 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.4/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```